# How to prohibit SSL access for unbound domain names

Tags: ssl, apache2

I use apache2 to deploy websites.

Now, I want to prohibit access for those unbound domain names.

For port 80, I use below rules and it works!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 8.8.8.8
    ServerAlias *

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-8.8.8.8.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-8.8.8.8.log combined       

    <Directory />
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, for port 443, I have tried many times, but still have no idea.

I have tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName 8.8.8.8
        ServerAlias *

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-8.8.8.8.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-8.8.8.8.log combined      

        <Directory />
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Could you please help me, thanks!

Please give me some advise, thanks!

Comment: For unbound hosts on port 443, I do not think the `Deny from all` rule will be evaluated. The scan of VirtualHosts will not result in a matching SSL certificate which means Apache will return a TLS error. Your rule is processed at a different layer after TLS negotiation. What is the error being reported? Update your question.

Comment: After enabling the above rules, all websites are forbidden.

Comment: What does your last comment mean? What did you change?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I've no idea about it. I just want to get some success suggestions. Thanks!